# lodash add keys to countBy function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a datasource as follows

```
[
  {
    "physicalId": 2110,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 2111,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 2111,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 4299,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 4299,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  }
]
```

and I'm using `lodash v4.17.4` to summarize the data in the following way:

```
[
  {
    "Sat Jun 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000": 2,
    "Sun Jun 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000": 3,
  }
]
```

However, i would like this returned as object in the format of

```
[
  {
    date: "Sat Jun 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000"
    total: 2
  },
    {
    date: "Sun Jun 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000"
    total: 3
  }
]
```

I've not been able to find a way to complete this in lodash. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `_.map` after `_.countBy`:

```
_.map(_.countBy(source, "closedDate"), (val, key) => ({ date: key, total: val }))
```

Comment: I have no keys to reference in the original result I'm gettting. its a date and a number

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think [this mapkey function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys) would help

Answer (score 0):

Using plain js, the following two reduce() would convert the original data to the desired format:

```js
let d = [{
    "physicalId": 2110,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 2111,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 2111,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 4299,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 4299,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  }
];

let r = [
  ...d.reduce((a, b) => {
    a.set(b.closedDate, a.has(b.closedDate) ? a.get(b.closedDate) + 1 : 1);
    return a;
  }, new Map)
].reduce((a, b) => {
  let [date, total] = [...b];
  return a.concat({date, total});
}, []);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using here ES6 syntax, with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) array helpers.

We are also using [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to change existing data inside our objects.

Here is working example.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "physicalId": 2110,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 2111,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 2111,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 4299,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "physicalId": 4299,
    "closedDate": "2017-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true
  }
]

const newData = data.reduce((previous, current) => {
  
  const recordExists = previous.find(record => record.date === current.closedDate);
  
  if (!recordExists) {
    return previous =  [ ...previous, { date: current.closedDate, total: 1 } ];
  }
  
  recordExists.total += 1;
  
  return [ ...previous, recordExists ];
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```