# How to get supplierName and count of items from a list?

Tags: javascript, lodash

In my vue application, there is a list with open purchase orders. Each order has a supplier name.

I like to generate a list with all supplier names and the number of open purchase orders they have.

With lodash, I'm able to generate a list of suppliers:

```
computed: {
  menuItems: function () {
    let mappedItems =  this.partsToOrder.map(function (parts) {
      return { supplierName: parts.supplier_name, supplierId: parts.supplier_id }
    })
    return _.uniqWith(mappedItems)
  }
},
```

How can I add the number of items for each supplier? It means, if a supplier has two open orders,  I like to have the supplierName once with the the count of items (2) like this:

```
{supplierName: 'Tech Ltd.', numOrders: 2}
```

Comment: you want to group the array? by the supplierName?

Comment: Yes, right. That's what i need

Comment: I edited tags for question, this simply has nothing to do with vue, it's just about Javascript :)

Comment: `_.map(_.countBy(data, "supplierName"), (val, key) => ({ supplierName: key, numOrders: val })) ` ... from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649268/3545099

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
  {supplierName: 'Tech Ltd.'},
  {supplierName: 'Tech Ltd.'},
  {supplierName: 'Tech Ltd.'},
  {supplierName: 'abc'},
  {supplierName: 'abc'},
  {supplierName: 'stackoverflow'},
  {supplierName: 'Dell'},
  {supplierName: 'Dell'},
];

let mappedData = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy('supplierName')
  .map((group, supplierName) => ({
    supplierName,
    numOrders: _.countBy(group, 'supplierName')[supplierName],
  }))
  .value();

console.log(mappedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```